# Google Apps administrator is not available. How can we regain access to our account?

Tags: google-workspace

The person who managed our Google Apps account has died and I need to access the accounts and manage some aspects including closing his business email address.

I do not have access to his email passwords etc., or mobile.

Comment: I expect you'll need to get in touch with Google directly.

Comment: Does this work? https://admin.google.com/example.com/ForgotAdminAccountInfo

Answer (score 3):

- If there are any other Super admins on your domain they can reset the password for the deceased admin's account and provide it to you.
- If your Google Apps domain was purchased through a reseller, reach out to them. They can assist you with this process through their reseller console.
- Try following all of the steps in the [Reset your admin password](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en) help article. If you have access to the backup email address, or phone for this admin this may work for you. Make sure to try every option in this article. You only need one to work.
- Google also has a process for requesting access to a deceased user's account found [here.](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/6357590?rd=3) This looks like it applies to any Google service, not just Google Apps.
- Google does provide support for Google Apps, but only if you have access to the admin console and can provide them with the pin found in it. [How to contact Google Apps support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213)